# Override dependency property with new keyword

Tags: c#, wpf, overriding, dependency-properties

If i want to add some custom action when setting a dependency property in WPF, is it correct, to override it with the `new` keyword in c#?

For example, i want to add custom behaviour when setting the ItemsSource of a control:

```
public new object ItemsSource
{
    get
    {
        return base.ItemsSource;
    }
    set
    {
        handleSelectionChanged = true;
        base.ItemsSource = value;
    }
}
```

Can this cause any side effects? I am not sure if i did it the correct way.

Thank you!

Comment: With `new` keyword you are not overriding

Comment: `new` only hides an inherit member of the base class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, the `new` keyword will hide the inherited member and you might lose some functionnality (haven't done the test yet)

Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752375(v=vs.100).aspx) explaining a few tips with Metadatas.

For your `ItemsSource`, I would suggest to attach a `PropertyChangedCallback` or a `CoerceValueCallback` to your initial property.